# How to add text in video without using ffpeg Android?

Tags: android, video, mediamuxer, mediaextractor, android-ffmpeg

I am using MediaMuxer and MediaExtractor to transcode video. Now i want to add text on video at certain position. How can i achieve this? Basically i am recording video and transcode it in lower resolution now i want to add text overlay without using ffmpeg. I tried to add watermark by using ffmpeg but it takes too much time. I am using [this](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java) library.This is my command:

```
String[] complexCommand = {"-y" ,"-i", "/storage/emulated/0/Download/VID.mp4","-strict",
                        "experimental", "-vf", "movie="
                        +"/storage/emulated/0/Download/iqm_logo.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w/2-overlay_w/2:450 [out]",
                        "-b:v", "1540k", "-c:v", "libx264","-threads","30","-preset","ultrafast","-r", "30","-s", "1080x1920","-c:a", "copy",
                        "/storage/emulated/0/Download/watermark.mp4"};
```

Comment: Do you just mean add the text overlay when you display the video, or do you want to save it with the video so it plays elsewhere? If you want to embed the text into the video then its going to be hard to find something that does not take a lot of processing on the Android device. ffmpeg is easy enough on Android with a wrapper library, in case that's a concern. If you can do it server side it will be much easier, of course. Its also worth being aware that subtitle/caption files are typically separate from the video in case this works for you - much less video processing if you know the times.

Comment: @Mick i want to save text with video. I tried with ffmpeg and i am able to add text on video but as i also compress the video it takes too much time to compress. FFMPEG takes 45 secs to compress 10 sec of video.

Comment: ffmpeg, as Im sure you know, is a large program supporting many formats and many different options when encoding, compressing etc. I would research 'fast ffmpeg compression' and you will see some of the options and tradeoffs. I'd experiment with ffmpeg on the cmd line on your computer and then see how it runs on Android. It will be slower on the Android due to less CPU, memory etc but it is also worth checking you have the necessary libraries (there are optional parts of ffmpeg). As ffmpeg gets so much attention and support, it will be hard to find a faster flexible compression approach.